# regex to accept phone number with or without spaces and also with or without +

Tags: java, regex

I have to write reqex to accept phone number with or without spaces and also with or without +

Here are the examples:

```
 + 01 917 1231234 
 +019171231234
 01 917 123 1234
 019171231234
```

Thanks,
Mk

Comment: phone no has random spaces?

Comment: what you have tried???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^\+?[\d ]+
```

`^` From the beginning
`\+?` check for a plus, but doesn't need it
`[\d ]+` check for numbers and spaces
you can also use

```
[\d ]{lower_limit,upper_limit}
```

to accept between lower and upper amount of characters

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all the spaces first then validate using regex:

```
\+{0,1}\d{12}
```

Example:

```
String phoneNo = "+ 01 917 1231234";
String patternString = "\\+{0,1}\\d{12}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phoneNo.replaceAll("\\s+",""));
boolean isValid = matcher.matches();
System.out.println(isValid);
```

Check the [**Demo here**](http://ideone.com/oSdLqA)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex.

```
"^\\+?(?:\\s*\\d){12}\\s*$"
```

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `\\+?` Matches an optional `+` symbol.
- `\\s*\\d` Matches zero or more space characters and a digit. And this pattern would be repeated exactly 12 times. So we got a match upto the 12 th digit.
- `\\s*` zero or more spaces.
- `$` End of the line anchor.

`matches` function won't need an anchored regex.

```
string.matches("\\+?(?:\\s*\\d){12}\\s*");
```